# Constructor Injection with CDI + Weld

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, weld, constructor-injection

I want to use Constructor Injection, as it makes my unit tests safer and easier to write: I can't forget to set the fields to be injected. CDI supports that, and the javadoc of the `@Inject` annotation says: "`@Inject` is optional for public, no-argument constructors when no other constructors are present. This enables injectors to invoke default constructors."

I understand that other standards require a no-arg constructor (e.g. JAX-RS; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467507/cdi-weld-unable-to-do-constructor-injection-of-resteasy-resource)), which is a bummer. But even for a simple class like:

```java
public class Bar {
    private final Foo foo;

    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Weld fails, saying: `DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Bar`. When I add the `@Inject` annotation, it works.

I really don't expect any bugs in Weld any more, as it's well established for years; I probably got something wrong. But maybe it slipped attention, just because the Jakarta EE community simply doesn't do any constructor injection.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the problem is? As the spec said, you don't need to add the `@Inject` annotation **if there's a public, no-argument constructor (implicit or explicit) _with no other constructors present_**. You have a single-argument constructor, thus you need to add the `@Inject` annotation to that constructor. If you also need a no-argument constructor you can add that as well, but you may have to forgo making `foo` final.

Comment: @Slaw I created a minimalistic demo project [on GitHub](https://github.com/t1/constructor-injection-demo). `Boundary` injects `Bar` which injects `Foo`. Works fine with the `@Inject` in line 8 of `Bar`.

When I remove that annotation, Weld complains: "org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Bar with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject demo.Boundary.bar".

Comment: Just to clarify, as you've already accepted an answer: You don't have a no-argument constructor by itself, which means the `@Inject` annotation is required as documented by the specification you quoted.

Comment: Exactly... I have over-read that, as it's so counter-intuitive. I thought it was required only when there are multiple constructors to disambiguate it. Thanks!

Comment: I'd argue it's not counter-intuitive. Think of it this way: Having a single, no-argument constructor is a _special case_. In Java, if a class doesn't declare a constructor a default no-argument constructor is implicitly added. It would be annoying to have to declare a no-argument constructor, with no custom logic, to simply to add the `@Inject` annotation. If you do declare a no-argument constructor, and that's the only constructor, then you don't have to add `@Inject` because there's no externally visible difference between that constructor and a default constructor.

Comment: Once you have more than one constructor you need to make it explicit which constructor is to be used. If you have only one constructor, but that constructor has arguments, you need to add `@Inject` as well; it explicitly marks the constructor as CDI-aware and thus allows you to control if the bean can be instantiated by the CDI container. In other words, you _always_ have to add the `@Inject` annotation with _one_ exception—(effectively) default constructors.

Comment: only default constructor => no constructor injection.

multiple constructors => use `@Inject` to mark the one to be used.

We agree on that. But when I have only one (non-default) constructor, I think CDI could take that: anything else wouldn't make any sense in my eyes. I think the standard is too conservative here. But I got the reasoning. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Weld bug.  As the [specification indicates](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#instantiation), you need `@javax.inject.Inject` on your constructor.  The only time you don't need it is when you have a zero-argument constructor and you do not wish for any other constructor to be called by the container.

Comment: You're right. It's confusing and limiting, but this is how it's specified.